# How to access data.table columns in a function in `j` without pass arguments in?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to build a function that can be used in `j` of a data table. I hope it doesn't require to a column to be passed in explicitly (I am lazy).

The following doesn't work `Error in test(x) : object 'x' not found`

```
test <- function(x=NULL){
    list(z=if (is.null(x)) evalq(x, envir=parent.frame()) else x)
}

a <- data.table(x=1:2, y=1:2)

a[, test(x)] // works well
a[, test()]  // error
```

If I do `a[, test(x)]` I get

```
> a[, test(x)]
   z
1: 1
2: 2
```

I hope `a[, test()]` give me same thing.

Comment: You should also describe the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it to work with something like:

```
test <- function(x=NULL){
    if (is.null(x)) get('x', parent.frame(3)[,list(x)]) else list(x)
}
```

but this is a really bad idea as it will break once you introduce a `by` to your `data.table` statement. That's because you're not giving `data.table` a chance to figure out what columns you're going to be using and, since it hasn't gained omnipotence just yet, once you obfuscate the columns you need in a function there isn't much it can do for you.

It might be a better idea to post what your actual problem is (or a closer approximation of it) and maybe you'll get alternative suggestions for a solution.

Comment: `parent.frame(3)!`, alright I will give up the idea of making the function dynamic scoping.

Comment: @colinfang I just realized that this was working by accident since `x` is the internal name of the calling `data.table`, so I corrected for that, but yeah - avoid doing this and I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve but take a look at `eval` and `quote`