# Use function instead of {} in j data.table

Tags: r, data.table

could you help me to understand why in data.table I could access column by name in {}, e.g.

```
dt <- data.table(x=1:2, y=1:2)
dt[,{
   list(z = x + y)
}]
```

But can't do the same in a function

```
test_sum <- function() {
   list(z = x + y)
}
dt[, test_sum()]
```

Is this the same as from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19958647/3021252?

If so, is it better to have functions like

```
test_sum2 <- function(data) {
   list(z = data$x + data$y)
}
dt[, test_sum2(.SD)]
```

or

```
test_sum3 <- function(x, y) {
   list(z = x + y)
}
dt[, test_sum3(x, y)]
```

Comment: @Frank ok, I'll move the comments to an answer. I'm simplifying a little, as more advanced parsing happens with e.g. `eval` statements, but after those are expanded, it just searches for column names in the expression tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your last option is the best. Your first option - not having any arguments is just bad practice as it's not clear to the reader that the function internally/magically uses external data (assuming you made it work). Second option is better, but you pass too much info. Your final option passes exact right amount of info, which plays well with data.table, since it will not have to provide the other columns in computations.

As far as *why* option one doesn't work, it's simply because data.table only provides those columns in the `j-expression` environment that it detects being used (by doing a simple text parse of the expression, which in this case is `test()`, which doesn't use any columns).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you'd want to do that, particularly after reading the linked question. You could in theory do this:

```
test_sum <- function() quote(list(z = x + y))
dt[, eval(test_sum)]
```

But as the linked answer says, you may run into problems once you start using `by`.

The columns should really be defined in your data.table call, so the better way to do it would be:

```
test_sum <- function(a, b) a + b
dt[, list(z = test_sum(x, y))]
```

or your `test_sum3` above.

I think you're confusing curly brackets as representing an anonymous function. They represent an expression, which will be executed in the current scope. See [Hadley Wickham's excellent chapter on non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) for more on eval and quote and other such things.